# How to make two Tasks run with an even distribution of cpu time

Tags: c#, async-await, task, thread-priority

They start out even, but eventually the processTasks never gets hits. 
Originally I had this as two threads when the tasks were simple. Someone suggested async/await tasks and being new to c# I had no reason to doubt them.

```
Task monitorTasks= new Task (monitor.start );
Task processTasks= new Task( () => processor.process(ref param, param2) );

monitorTasks.Start();
processTasks.Start();

await processTasks;
```

Have I executed this wrong? Is my problem inevitable while running two tasks? Should they be threads? How to avoid.

*edit*

To clarify. The tasks are never intended to end. They will always be processing and monitoring while triggering events that notify watchers of monitor outputs or processor outputs.

Comment: u need to wait all tasks.... a simple google will help

Comment: Where have you seen that it's a good idea to use the `Task` constructor?

Comment: I haven't seen the task constructor used like I have. I Come from c++, it compiled and ran, I'm new to c#. Why is it so bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get tasks to run evenly. 
The monitor task was getting constantly flooded whereas the processor task was getting tasks less frequently, which is when I suspect the monitor task took over.

Since no one could help me, 
My solution was to turn them back into threads and set the priority of the threads.Lower than normal for the monitor task, and higher than normal for the processor task. 
This seems to have solved my problem.

Comment: @Darem better approach for what? my tasks never end. Those approaches don't at all address what I was asking about.

Comment: Yes, but my tasks are designed to always be receiving new work. The work is never finished. I'm not sure what is confusing about "My tasks never end"

Answer (score 1):

If you await on a `Task.WhenAll` then it will wait until all tasks have been processed

```
await Task.WhenAll(monitorTasks, processTasks)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: all tasks will never end.

Comment: and how does that help with even distribution of computation while the tasks are running?

Comment: @codeMetis next time you ask a question, be sure to add the appropriate information about what it is you are doing, trying to do, what is not working and what you expect to happen.

Comment: I thought I had. I meant "how to stop" as in how to stop them being uneven, referring to the first half of the sentence. I understand how it was confusing and very definitely my bad. However, I mentioned even distribution twice and stopping never in the body of description. I understand the confusion, but i felt I had described what I was trying to  do (run two tasks) and what was not working (one was not getting hit) and what I expected to happen ( have them both be hit evenly)

Comment: @KevinSmith no. No stopping. they never end. they never get cancelled   - aside from when the entire program is shutdown. I do not care about stopping. I care about even distribution of time on the cpu. Both threads aren't being run concurrently. On the single core they take turns on a master thread, one spawned thread was getting more time on that master thread than the other spawned thread, I wanted them to have the same amount of time on the master thread.

Answer (score 0):

`Task.WaitAll` blocks the current thread until everything has completed.

`Task.WhenAll` returns a task which represents the action of waiting until everything has completed.

---

[Task.WhenAll Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Creates a task that will complete when all of the Task objects in an
>   enumerable collection have completed.

[Task.WaitAll Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Waits for all of the provided Task objects to complete execution.

---

If you want to block wait on started tasks (which is seemingly what you want)

```
Task monitorTasks= new Task (monitor.start );
Task processTasks= new Task( () => processor.process(ref param, param2) );

monitorTasks.Start();
processTasks.Start();

Task.WaitAll(new Task[]{monitorTasks,processTasks})
```

If you are using `async` `await`, see [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Then you could do something like this

```
var task1 = DoWorkAsync();
var task2 = DoMoreWorkAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `Task.WaitAll` anymore

Comment: @KevinSmith hrm, you may be right, but whenall isn't going to help at the end of OP code

Comment: The tasks never end though.